# DBus synchronous call timeout

Tags: c, glib, dbus, c-api

I have a DBus server which exposes a method that requires a huge time to complete (about 3 minutes).
The client performs a synchronous call to this method.

The problem is, after exactly 25 secs the client throws an error because 'did not receive a reply'.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the client, so I cannot make the call asynchronous, as it should be.

I tried to use this line in my server configuration:

```
<limit name = "reply_timeout">240000</limit>
```

but the situation does not change.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `limit` parameter configures the bus daemon, which is only one of the processes involved. The others are the client and the server, and the particular D-Bus library used on each end may have a default timeout for synchronous messages. And 25 seconds is indeed the  `_DBUS_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_VALUE` in libdbus, the C reference implementation.

Changing the timeout in the client, for example in [dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#ga8d6431f17a9e53c9446d87c2ba8409f0), is easier than changing the API to be asynchronous.